# Parsing the data from a verilog file

Tags: regex, tcl

I am a beginner in TCL scripting. I am working on parsing the data from a Verilog file to a xls file as below.

Input Verilog file contains following data:

```
Inferred components
Operator   Signedness   Inputs   Outputs CellArea Line Col      Filename     
=====================================================================================================
apn
u_apn_ttp_logic
abc
u_apn_wgt_op_rd_u_apn_sca_u_part_sel1_sl_69_33
module:shift_right_vlog_unsigned_4662_7709
very_fast/barrel        >>      x          25x5       25        223.02   69  33 part_select.v 
=====================================================================================================
apn
u_apn_ttp_logic
u_apn_wgt_op_rd_u_apn_scale_u_part_sel1_sub00283545
module:sub_signed_4513_5538
very_fast               -       signed     11x24      25        152.80    0   0 a                 
=====================================================================================================
```

(This is a long file…)

The parsing will end after the last section:

```
=====================================================================================================
apn
u_apn_start_ctrl_final_adder_add_212_41
module:add_unsigned_carry_882
very_fast                +       unsigned   32x32x1    32        120.39  212  41 feu_start_ctrl.v 
=====================================================================================================
```

I want to extract the data as below , consider first section

```
Top name=apn
Instance=u_apn_ttp_logic/abc/u_apn_wgt_op_rd_u_feu_scale_u_part_select1_srl_69_33
Module = shift_right_vlog_unsigned_4662_7709
Architecture=very_fast/barrel  
Operator = >>
Sign=x
Input Size = 25x5
Output = 25
Area = 223.02
Column = 69
Row = 33
File Name = part_select.v
```

I am stucked at a point while implementing this.

below is my approach for the same:

```
set fd "[open "path_data.v" r]" 
set flag 0
   while {[gets $fd line] !=-1} {
      if {[regexp "\===*" $line]} {
         while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
            append data "$line "
            if {[regexp "\====*" $line]} {
               break
            }  }
set topname [lindex $data 0]
regexp {(^[a-z]*) (.*) (.*module)} $data match topname instance sub3
puts "top name :$topname "
puts "instance: $instance"

}

close $fd
```

I am able to output `topname` and `instance` name only, not other values 
Also please help me extract these values.

Answer (score 0):

With this sort of task, it *really* helps if you put parts of the task into procedures that do just a simpler bit. For example, suppose we were to split the processing of a single section into its own procedure. Since it is only going to do one section (presumably a lot shorter than the overall file), it can work on a string (or list of strings) instead of having to process by lines, which will make things greatly easier to comprehend.

For example, it would handle just this input text:

```
apn
u_apn_ttp_logic
abc
u_apn_wgt_op_rd_u_apn_sca_u_part_sel1_sl_69_33
module:shift_right_vlog_unsigned_4662_7709
very_fast/barrel        >>      x          25x5       25        223.02   69  33 part_select.v
```

We might handle that like this:

```
proc processSection {sectionText} {
    set top ""
    set instance ""
    set module ""
    set other {}
    foreach line [split $sectionText "\n"] {
        if {$top eq ""} {
            set top [string trim $line]
            continue
        }
        if {$module eq ""} {
            # This regular expression matches lines starting with “module:” and
            # extracts the rest of the line
            if {[regexp {^module:(.*)} $line -> tail]} {
                set module [string trim $tail]
            } else {
                append instance [string trim $line] "/"
            }
            continue
        }
        # This regular expression matches a sequence of non-space characters, and
        # the -all -inline options make regexp return a list of all such matches.
        lappend other {*}[regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
    }
    # Remember to remove trailing “/” character of the instance
    set instance [string trimright $instance /]

    # Note that this splits apart the list in $other
    outputSectionInfo $top $instance $module {*}$other
}
```

We also need something to produce the output. I've split it into its own procedure as it is often nice to keep parsing separate from output.

```
proc outputSectionInfo {top instance module arch op sgn in out area col row file} {
    # Output the variables
    foreach {label varname} {
        "Top name" top
        "Instance" instance
        "Module"   module
        "Architecture" arch
        "Operator" op
        "Sign"     sgn
        "Input Size" in
        "Output"   out
        "Area"     area
        "Column"   col
        "Row"      row
        "File Name" file
    } {
        # Normally, best to avoid using variables whose names are in variables, but
        # for printing out like this, this is actually really convenient.
        puts "$label = [set $varname]"
    }
}
```

Now that we've got a section handler and output generator (and you can verify for yourself that these do sensible things, as they're quite a bit simpler than what you were trying to do in one go), we just need to feed the sections from the file into it, skipping over the header. The code does that, and *just* does that.

```
set fd [open "path_data.v"]
set flag 0
while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp {^=====+$} $line]} {
        if {$flag} {
            processSection [string trimright $accumulator "\n"]
        }
        set flag 1
        set accumulator ""
    } else {
        append accumulator $line "\n"
    }
}
close $fd
```

---

Your immediate problem was that your code was closing the channel too early, but that was in turn caused by your confusion over indentation, and that was in turn caused by you trying to do too much in one place. Splitting things up to make the code more comprehensible is the fix for this sort of issue, as it makes it much easier to tell that the code is definitely correct (or definitely wrong).

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work on the real data, but it is at least a lot easier to see what is going wrong and to verify the pieces.

Comment: Hi Donal,

Thanks for your support,

I tried with your code but there are errors coming, I also tried with setting flag inside first if loop, 

Also please help me to understand below command,

"outputSectionInfo $top $instance $module {*}$other"

Answer (score 0):

I worked on above script, and here is my code for the same. This code won't work if there is an empty line after "========" line

But I would like to explore your code as it is well organised.

```
    set fd "[open "path_data.v" r]"

set fd1 "[open ./data_path_rpt.xls w+]"
puts $fd1 "Top Name\tInstance\tModule\tArchitecture\tOperator\tSign\tInput Size\tOutput size\tArea\tLine number\tColumn number\tFile Name"
set data {}
while {[gets $fd line] !=-1} {
if {[regexp "\===*" $line]} {
        set data {}; set flag 0
        while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} { append data "$line "
                if {[regexp {[a-z]\.v} $line]} {  set flag 1;break}  }
puts "$data\n\n"
    if {$flag} {
       set topname [lindex $data 0]
       regexp {(^[a-z]*) (.*) (.*module\:)(.*)} $data match topname instance sub3 sub4
      set inst_name {} ;
      foreach txt $instance { 
         append inst_name "$txt\/"
      }
       set instance [string trim $inst_name "\/"]
       set module [lindex $sub4 0]
       set architecture [lindex $sub4 1]
       set operator [lindex $sub4 2]
       set sign [lindex $sub4 3]
       set input_size [lindex $sub4 4]
       set output_size [lindex $sub4 5]
       set area [lindex $sub4 6]
       set linenum [lindex $sub4 7]
       set col_num [lindex $sub4 8]
       set file_name [lindex $sub4 9]
       puts $fd1 "$topname\t$instance\t$module\t$architecture\t$operator\t$sign\t$input_size\t$output_size\t$area\t$linenum\t$col_num\t$file_name"
       set data {} ; set flag 0
}}
}
close $fd1
close $fd
```